# Class isn't abstract but I get Error C2259: cannot instantiate abstract class

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-errors

I'm trying to implement a Strategy pattern in C++, but I get the following error:

Error 1 error C2259: 'LinearRootSolver' : cannot instantiate abstract class

Here's my code (the line where the error is, is marked with a comment).
Class that uses strategy pattern (context):

```
bool Isosurface::intersect(HitInfo& result, const Ray& ray, float tMin, float tMax) {
    INumericalRootSolver *rootSolver = new LinearRootSolver(); // error here
    [...]
}
```

And here's my strategy pattern classes:

```
class INumericalRootSolver {
public:
    virtual void findRoot(Vector3* P, float a, float b, Ray& ray) = 0;
};

class LinearRootSolver : public INumericalRootSolver {
public:
    void findRoot(Vector3& P, float a, float b, Ray& ray) {
        [...]
    }
};
```

I can't see why I get an error for trying to instantiate an abstract class in the intersect method at the top?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 void findRoot(Vector3* P, float a, float b, Ray& ray) = 0;
                    //^^
```

and

```
void findRoot(Vector3& P, float a, float b, Ray& ray) 
              //^^
```

parameter type mismatch, so `findRoot` inherited form based class is still a pure virtual function (not overriding), which make the `LinearRootSolver` class an abstract class. When you do:

```
  INumericalRootSolver *rootSolver = new LinearRootSolver();
```

it tries to create an object of abstract class, you got the compiler error.

Comment: Oh my god. That's an evil typo, thanks for finding it for me. Heh.

Answer (score 2):

Your definition for `LinearRootSolver::findRoot` has the wrong signature. In particular, the first argument should be a pointer according to the declaration in `INumericalRootSolver`:

```
void findRoot(Vector3* P, float a, float b, Ray& ray) {
//                   ^ Here
    [...]
}
```

In C++11, you can avoid this mistake by using the `override` keyword:

```
void findRoot(Vector3& P, float a, float b, Ray& ray) override {
    [...]
}
```

This wouldn't compile because the function doesn't override a function from the base class.

Answer (score 2):

Your derived class uses references and your interface uses pointers.

You need to have the same method signature for both methods in order to get a proper override.